# What advantages are there to using Parse.com JS SDK over Parse.com REST API with AngularJS application?

Tags: angularjs, rest, parse-platform, sdk

I am using the `Parse.com JS SDK` for `AngularJS` project. I am using Parse promises and AngularJS `$q` service to bind Parse data to the AngularJS `$scope` object. I am wondering, though, are there any advantages to using `JS SDK` over `REST API`, except for the query syntax sugar and authentication management through currentUser method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you need to ask yourself this:

- Do you want to make everything yourself (thereby having total control of what happens)?
- OR do you want leverage other peoples code, and just start building your application on top of that?

My experience is, when building apps with AngluarJS and Parse JS SDK, is that it takes some time to understand how the SDK is working - BUT when you familiarize yourself with it, the gains are enormous to how fast you can develop you application.

As you are stating yourself - Sessionhandling, for when a user has been logged in and Query-building-syntax (not forget about relational queries) has just been taking care of for you. That is, at least IMO, enough for me to choose the SDK.

Last takeaway from a AngularJS/ParseSDK developer is - use Angular's $q-service as promise handling, when working on your client. That way you will never end up in a missing digest cycle, thus calling $scope.$apply(). 
Just remember that $q is NOT available in Parse's Cloud Code, here you will have to use their own Parse.Promise()-promise service.

Hope these points gave you some insight.